# Bash script to extract tgz with input file as a parameter

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to create a script and give it an input file as a parameter so it will extract the file and then change directory into the extracted file and run another script that is included in the extracted directory.

All I need the script to do is tar -xvzf input_file.tgz but instead of calling that I would like to do something like extract input_file.tgz, so it would extract and do the rest of the steps i want it to do. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Certainly there is, why should that not be possible? Just as you said: you make a script. Since that is obviously not the answer you are waiting for: so what is your _real_ question here?

Comment: *Is there a way to do this?* Yes, this is exactly what scripting is for. Just test that `$1` is provided to the script, that it is a file and has the required extension. Then separate the path from the filename, untar with the `-C` option and then change to the directory and finish running the commands you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following would do exactly what you're asking. If you call the script `extract.sh`, you would simply call `./extract.sh` and provide a filename.

```
#!/bin/bash
fname=$1

if [ -f $fname ]; then # if the file exists
    tar -xvzf $fname # tar it
    cd ${fname%.*} # the `%.*` will extract `filename` from `filename.tgz` and cd into it
fi
```

**Edit**: As @KLibby pointed out in the comments, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/517891/bash-script-for-extracting-archives-how-to-make-the-script-ask-for-folder-dest) is more details for how to error check the parameter (the `tgz` file). I'll add the script below.

If you want to allow several different possible archive formats, you would want to do something as the following [1]:

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRIPTNAME="${0##*/}"

# if the archive file does not exist,
# call this function with a message
err() {
    printf >&2 "$SCRIPTNAME: $*\n"
    exit 1
}

ARC="$1"

# check to make sure the file (now in `$ARC`) exists
# else, fail
[[ -f $ARC ]] || err $"'$ARC' does not exist"

# if it's a symbolic link, we'll want to read its value
ARC="$(readlink -f "$ARC")"

# un-archive using the correct program given
# the file's extension
case "$ARC" in
    *.tar.bz2)   tar xjf "$ARC"     ;;
    *.tar.gz)    tar xzf "$ARC"     ;;
    *.bz2)       bunzip2 "$ARC"     ;;
    *.rar)       unrar e "$ARC"     ;;
    *.gz)        gunzip "$ARC"      ;;
    *.tar)       tar xf "$ARC"      ;;
    *.tbz2)      tar xjf "$ARC"     ;;
    *.tgz)       tar xzf "$ARC"     ;;
    *.zip)       unzip "$ARC"       ;;
    *.Z)         uncompress "$ARC"  ;;
    *.7z)        7z x "$ARC"        ;;
    *)           echo "'$ARC' cannot be extracted by $SCRIPTNAME" ;;
esac

# extract the `filename` from `filename.tgz`
dir=${ARC%.*}

# `cd` to the directory if it exists
if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
    cd $dir
fi
```

[1] Adapted from https://askubuntu.com/questions/517891/bash-script-for-extracting-archives-how-to-make-the-script-ask-for-folder-dest.

Comment: See the first answer to [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/517891/bash-script-for-extracting-archives-how-to-make-the-script-ask-for-folder-dest) question, for more details on how to 
error check the parameters.

Comment: @MichaelRecachinas, Could this be used in combination with an expect script? Let's say i already have an expect script written, i want to extract and cd into the directory then run an expect script. How would I be able to merge the expect script with your sample script above?

Comment: or can i just do this # `cd` to the directory if it exists
if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
    cd $dir; ./my_expect script #this is global in my bin
fi

Comment: never mind figured it out and it works thanks again !